# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class in Index.php in magento 2

Tags: php, grid, admin-panel, magento2.2

This is my Controller file Index.php

```
<?php

namespace OX\HomeSlider\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;

abstract class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    protected $_resultPage;
    protected $_resultPageFactory = false;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        //Call page factory to render layout and page content
        $this->_setPageData();
        return $this->getResultPage();
    }

    /*
     * Check permission via ACL resource
     */

    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('OX_HomeSlider::post_manage');
    }

    public function getResultPage()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_resultPage)) {
            $this->_resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        }
        return $this->_resultPage;
    }

    protected function _setPageData()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->getResultPage();
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu('OX_HomeSlider::post');
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend((__('Posts')));

        //Add bread crumb
        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('OX'), __('OX'));
        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('Home Slider'), __('Manage Blogs'));

        return $this;
    }


}
```

I have got below error
[image]

Please suggest a solution

Comment: remove abstract keyword from class

Comment: If i removed abstract keyword it will shows error in that line. It had shown below error in NetBeans , (\namespace\module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index is not abstract & does not override abstract methos execute() in \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Interface ). In terminal it shows core class not found while compiling.

Comment: Please go through code of any default Magento adminhtml module and check if your file structure and classes are correct.